# Change Bibliography style to APA

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

I have the code below to define my bibliography style. I looked into different threads here but they are all using packages and I am not sure how to implement those solutions without messing up rest of the format.

```
\def\thebibliography#1{\chapter*{\bibname\@mkboth
  {\uppercase{\bibname}}{\uppercase{\bibname}}}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
  \list{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}{\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
    \leftmargin\labelwidth
    \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
    \usecounter{enumiv}%
    \let\p@enumiv\@empty
    \def\theenumiv{\arabic{enumiv}}}%
    \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus.33em minus.07em}%
    \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
    \sfcode`\.=\@m}
```

This is from a [template](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/neu-ece-thesis) available on ShareLatex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightly tested. This uses the `apacite` package for APA style, along with `natbib` for `natbib` style citation commands.   Make sure that you have no other `\bibliographystyle` commands in your document.

```
\documentclass[PHD]{macro/neu_msthesis}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
\def\thebibliography#1{\chapter*{\bibname\@mkboth
  {\uppercase{\bibname}}{\uppercase{\bibname}}}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
  \list{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}{\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
    \leftmargin\labelwidth
    \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
    \usecounter{enumiv}%
    \let\p@enumiv\@empty
    \def\theenumiv{\arabic{enumiv}}}%
    \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus.33em minus.07em}%
    \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
    \sfcode`\.=\@m}
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks. It does change the brackets to parentheses but still uses arabic numbers rather than authoryear style.

Comment: @Masoud Then you need to make a minimal document and edit your question to show that. Did you delete your `.aux` files and recompile?

Comment: yeah, I cleared all the cache files. Let me try to see if I can provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Masoud Sorry, I forgot to mention that you need to remove any other `\bibliographystyle` commands in the document and add `\bibliographystyle{apacite}`. There's probably a `\bibliographystyle{plain}` lurking around in your document.

Comment: Now it works. I had `\bibliographystyle{plain}` just changed it to `apacite` and it worked. Thanks.